# How are objects passed and what are the associated overheads?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, objective-c++

I've got a basic question about obj-c coding, say I have two classes represented by the variables:

```
ClassA *classA; 
ClassB *classB;
```

If I wanted to access `ClassB` from `ClassA`, I could pass the object in `classB` as an argument into any `ClassA` method and use it accordingly.

What is the overhead of this transaction, and do larger allocated memory objects have a higher overhead against smaller allocated objects? Or is the transaction just a simple 4byte pointer? (How are objects passed?)

Another question, if I wanted to retain `ClassB *classB` in the header after initializing using a passing argument object of `classB`. Would this be less expensive than consistently passing arguments to each of my individual methods?

Thanks,
Oliver.

Comment: Objects are passed by value, as a pointer. I'm curious, do you have a performance issue or are you optimizing in advance?

Comment: It's not unreasonable to want to understand the fundamental issues with regard to performance before you start coding.  That's not the much-maligned "optimizing in advance", just good programming practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're passing pointers, there's not really any more cost to passing one that there is in passing an `int`.  Same thing for storing a value in an object -- no real difference (ignoring any retains you may do) than there is in storing an `int`.

Of course, when you store a pointer to an object in another object you should generally `retain` it, but that's a whole `nother discussion.